# run a scheduled task once a day

Tags: java

My requirement is I want to schedule a task that should run once a day.For that I am using following code:

```
public class setAutoReminder {
    EscalationDAO escalationDAO=new EscalationDAO();
    final  SendMail sendMail=new SendMail();
    public void fetch(){
        Date date=new Date();
        Timer timer = new Timer();


        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                int number=escalationDAO.getAutoReminder();
                System.out.println(number);
                if(number>0) {
                    sendMail.sendMail();
                }
            }
        },date, 1000000000);
    }
}
```

but this code runs multiple times.I want it to runs once a day.What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at spring `@Scheduled` or quartz

Comment: eh , why there is 1000000000 ?

Comment: 1000000000000 because i wanted to delay it maximum

Comment: RC i am completely unaware about spring.can you give me the code

Comment: @milind  try http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/scheduling.html

Comment: May I know which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows operating system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have many scheduled jobs then don't add all the Spring baggage.
Keep it simple.

```
Date date=new Date();
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
     public void run(){
          System.out.println("Im Running..."+new Date());
     }
},date, 24*60*60*1000);//24*60*60*1000 add 24 hours delay between job executions.
```

This will do the stuff.

-Siva

Answer (score 4):

With Spring (using lombok `@Slf4j`):

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SetAutoReminder 
{
    @Autowired
    private EscalationDAO escalationDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SendMail sendMail;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *") // everyday at midnight
    public void fetch(){
        final int number = escalationDAO.getAutoReminder();
        log.debug("Today number: {}", number);
        if (number>0) {
           sendMail.sendMail();
        }
    }
}
```

Tutorial on spring scheduling: [springsource blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

Comment: Will I have to include any jars for this.What is that lombok

Comment: Yes, you need to setup and configure spring. Perhaps Quartz is a better approach if you don't want a lot of dependencies.

Comment: @jontro not in spring, see [Scheduled javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--)

Comment: Thanks, the format being different is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need a scheduler, like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)